# Quadratic inequality powered by 2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

i was doing some pre-calc until i stumbled on this problem:

$$(x^2-2x-3)^{1999}(x^2-6x+5)^{2000}\ge0$$

Powering to 1999 is like powering to 1, so i wrote:

$$(x^2-2x-3)^{1999}\ge0   = (x^2-2x-3)\ge0$$

Solved it, and the answers are -1,3. When i study the sign, i get $1\le x \land x\ge 3$

After i graph it, i go to the main problem:

$$(x^2-6x+5)^{2000}\ge0$$

Powering to 2000 is like powering to $2$, so i wrote

$$(x^2-6x+5)^{2000}\ge0 = (x^2-6x+5)^2\ge0$$

So my thoughts are:

1. I know that any number powered to 2 in this case will be bigger or equal to 0. After i solve it (roots are 5,1), how should i approach?
2. At the end, the answer is $(-\infty,-1]\cup(1)\cup[3,+ \infty)$

Why should i put exclude the one?

And what would happen if the inequality would be reversed?

Comment: When $x=1$ you have that $1^2-2\cdot 1-3=-4$ but you also have that $1^2-6\cdot 1+5=0$ so $-4\cdot 0=0$. Also you shouldn't write $(x^2-2x-3)^{1999}\geq 0=(x^2-2x-3)\geq 0$ but instead $(x^2-2x-3)^{1999}\geq 0 \iff(x^2-2x-3)\geq 0$ (though this might just be because you didn't know how to write $\iff$).

Answer (score 2):

The term $(x^2-6x+5)^2$ doesn't change the sign when it is positive and make the inequality satisfy at equality when it is equal to zero.

From solving $x^2-2x-3 \geq 0$, you have obtain $x \le -1$ or $x \ge 3$.

Solving $x^2-6x+5=0$, $(x-1)(x-5)=0$ means we have to include $1$ and $5$ into our solution set and hence,  the result.

In summary:

$$(x^2-2x-3)^{1999}(x^2-6x+5)^{2000}\ge0$$

is equivalent to -

$$x^2-2x-3 \geq 0 \text{ or } x^2-6x+5=0$$.

Comment: So basically, if i have an inequality powered to the second, since it's positive for every x, i just need to check where actually we have the equality?

Comment: Yes, the interesting case would be when things are zero.